# PHP script to connect MYSQL database to Android DevicePHP Error

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

I am having a problem with the connection to my PHP script, it keeps on returning "Oops! Its this one." - which is my error message if it could not inset into the mySQL database.

```
///PHP SCRIPT

<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("postgrad.nmmu.ac.za", "Christian", "Christian123", "drmdb");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


// array for JSON response

$response = array();
$PointerID = $_POST['PointerID'];
$ActivityID = $_POST['ActivityID'];

$StartX = $_POST['StartX'];
$EndX = $_POST['EndX'];
$StartY = $_POST['StartY'];
$EndY = $_POST['EndY'];

$Content = $_POST['Content'];
$Head = $_POST['Head'];

$NodeID = $_POST['NodeID'];
$Step = $_POST['Step'];

$result = mysqli_query(
    $con,
    "INSERT INTO pointersequence(PointerID, ActivityID, StartX, StartY, EndX, EndY, Content, Head, NodeID, Step)  VALUES('$PointerID','$ActivityID', '$StartX', '$StartY', '$EndX', '$Content', '$Head', '$NodeID', '$Step')"
);


// check if row inserted or not

if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Person successfully created hahaha.";
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! Its this one.";
    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
mysql_close($con);
?>



    OUTPUT: Oops! Its this one.




    //Method in Android to Insert
                private void UploadPointerSequence() {
                            int num11 = 1;
                            final String URL12 = "http://drm.csdev.nmmu.ac.za/UploadPointerSequence.php";

                            for (int x = 0; x <= PointerSequence.size() - 1; x++) {
                                List<NameValuePair> param12 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                                param12.add(new BasicNameValuePair("PointerID", String
                                        .valueOf(num11)));
                                num11++;
                                param12.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ActivityID", String
                                        .valueOf(PointerSequence.get(x).getActivityID())));
                                param12.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StartX", String
                                        .valueOf(PointerSequence.get(x).getStartX())));
                                param12.add(new BasicNameValuePair("StartY", String
                                        .valueOf(PointerSequence.get(x).getStartY())));
                                param12.add(new BasicNameValuePair("EndX", String
                                        .valueOf(PointerSequence.get(x).getEndX())));
                                param12.add(new BasicNameValuePair("EndY", String
                                        .valueOf(PointerSequence.get(x).getEndY())));
                                param12.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content", PointerSequence
                                        .get(x).getContent()));
                                param12.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Head", String
                                        .valueOf(PointerSequence.get(x).isHead())));
                                param12.add(new BasicNameValuePair("NodeID", String
                                        .valueOf(PointerSequence.get(x).getNodeID())));
                                param12.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Step", String
                                        .valueOf(PointerSequence.get(x).getStep())));

                                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL12, "POST",
                                        param12);
                            }
                        }

>JSON CLASS:



            public class JSONParser {

                static InputStream is = null;
                static JSONObject jObj = null;
                static String json = "";

                // constructor
                public JSONParser() {

                }

                // function get json from url
                // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
                public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                        List<NameValuePair> params) {

                    // Making HTTP request
                    try {

                        // check for request method
                        if(method == "POST"){
                            // request method is POST
                            // defaultHttpClient
                            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                            is = httpEntity.getContent();

                        }else if(method == "GET"){
                            // request method is GET
                            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                            url += "?" + paramString;
                            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                            is = httpEntity.getContent();
                        }           
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    try {
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = null;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        is.close();
                        json = sb.toString();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                    }

                    // try parse the string to a JSON object
                    try {
                        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                    }

                    // return JSON String
                    return jObj;

                }
            }

        Thanks in Advance!
```

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs with `mysql_close($con);` use `mysqli_close($con);` - Those two APIs do not mix.

Comment: You also have a few stray `>` in `>   // array for JSON response` and `>   // array for JSON response` - If those are part of your code remove them. Your code's commenting is confusing.

Comment: Sorry, my commenting was a little rushed...sorry about that!

Comment: I have made the change from  mysql_close($con); to mysqli_close($con); however I still receive the same error returning

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: using the error reporting sadly did not yield anything